# Prevent const class function from calling non-const class function on reference member

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, const-correctness

Excuse me for the pretty obscure title, but it does kinda say it all. This is what I mean

```
class A
{
    void DoSomething(); // non-const
}
Class B
{
public:
    B(A& a) : _a(a) { }
    // const function
    void DoSomethingElse() const
    {
        // Is there a way to disallow this?
        _a.DoSomething();
    }
    void DoEvenMore()
    {
        // Should be OK
        _a.DoSomething();
    }
private:
    // Can't make it const A& because it needs
    // be non-const for non-const functions
    A& _a; // A reference
}
```

So is there a way I can prevent `B::DoSomethingElse()` from calling `A::DoSomething()`?
However, `B::DoEventMore()` which is not `const` should be able to keep on calling.

I'm using Visual C++ 2013.

The code above would demonstrate a *bug* in my program. (In my scenario class A would unload the calling code's object/`this` pointer.) Since the point of const-correctness would be to prevent these kind of errors, I was just wondering if there's a way to check for this at compile time.

In the application I'm writing the function wouldn't seem dangerous to call at all. When calling it from `DoEvenMore()` the result would be the same, except that the destruction of `B` is deferred until the function is done running.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using the `_a` data member directly create accessor functions with `const` and non-`const` overloads. This will cause the `const` overload to be selected when called from within `const` member functions of `B`, which in turn prevents you from calling non-`const` functions of `A`.

```
A const& GetA() const { return _a; }
A& GetA() { return _a; }


void DoSomethingElse() const
{
    GetA().DoSomething(); // error
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. There's no way to make it implicit, right? (Omitting the call.)

Comment: @Aidiakapi If you mean by accessing `_a` directly, then no, there isn't. Since `_a` itself is not `const` you're free to call non-`const` member functions using it.

Answer (score 5):

The rules for "constness" make the object itself immutable but does not affect the constness of pointed to/referred objects. If you want to access a `const` reference *only* when you use a `const` method, you need to create a method overloaded on constness that returns either a reference or a const reference.

```
class B {
private:
    inline A& a() { return _a; }
    inline const A& a() const { return _a; }
public:
    // ...
};
```